# React js small component performance impact

Tags: reactjs, performance

Does break reactjs application with lot of very small components have impact of performance application ?

For example :  a table where each cell is a component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really you would be amazed to know that facebook has near about 30,000  component and still achieve high performance. React uses VIRTUAL DOM and it is smart enough to analyze the changes in each component and rerenders the changed component leaving aside the rest of the other components. You can read this article which enlights

=> [Efficient React Components: A Guide to Optimizing React Performance](https://www.toptal.com/react/optimizing-react-performance)